# Dynamic Matrix in Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a dynamic matrix in python? I have huge amounts of data, that I have to represent in a matrix form. Currently it would have 283228 rows and 193886 columns.

I want to be able to initialize the matrix without values, by just specifying the number of rows and columns.

I should be able to add rows or columns dynamically to the existing matrix.

Finally, I should be able to add values like this

```
Matrix[row][column] = value
```

Comment: What you're describing is a *sparse matrix*. Unless you need to fix the size, the simplest implementation is `defaultdict(dict)`.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Just what do you mean by "initialize the matrix without values" and "add rows or columns dynamically to the existing matrix"? Do you mean you do not care which values are placed in the matrix or that you do not want any memory space taken up by initial values or something else? Do you want to add a *new* row or column that changes the size of the matrix or do you want the memory allocation for the row or column of the same-sized matrix to be done dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have huge vectors/matrixes use numpy anyway !

If you know the dimensions in advance, you can do:

```
nrow, ncol= 4,10
M0 = np.zeros((nrow,ncol))

vx = np.arange(nrow) + 10
vy = np.arange(ncol) + 10

M0[2,:] = vy
M0[:,5] +=  vx
M0

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 11.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 27., 16., 17., 18., 19.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 13.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If you do not know the dimensions in advance, you can check them, once you have some vectors as vx or vy:

```
nx = vx.shape[0]
ny = vy.shape[0]
nx,ny

(4, 10)
```

If you realy want to start with an empty matrix, you can do:

```
M1 = np.array([])
M1 = np.hstack((M1,vy))
M1

array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19.])
```

or:

```
M2 = np.r_['c',vx]
M2

matrix([[10],
        [11],
        [12],
        [13]])
```

Perhaps you should be more precise what type of dynamics on the matrix is needed and - as @jonrsharpe mentioned - wether you have sparse data in the matrix.